# Change of coordinate in ordinary differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I would like to make a change of coordinate so I can solve the following ODE with the method of separation of variables.
My ODE is:
$x'=x^\frac{2}{3}+t^2$ with $x>0$.

How can I do this and what kind of coordinates should be considered here?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First making $x = z^3$ we have

$$
3z^2 z'-z^2-t^2=0
$$

and then with $z = \frac tu$

$$
3tu'+(u^3+u-3)u = 0
$$

which is separable.